# What is the actual return value type of Python Paramiko Channel.recv()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, python-2.x, paramiko

I'm having an old Python script in version 2.7, which uses the function Paramiko [`Channel.recv()`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.recv) method. I'm trying to migrate the script into a Python version 3 (and Paramiko 2.7.1), but the documentation says:

> :return: received data, as a `str`/`bytes`.

Since the major problems when migrating from Python 2 to Python 3 are the different basestrings, I need a more concrete specification of the return type.

What does the function's return type depend on? Or: How can I be sure, that the return value is always the same (e.g. bytestring)?

Some code-snippet:

```
t = paramiko.Transport(socklike_obj)
t.start_client()
t.auth_password(usr, pw)
chan = t.open_session()
nbytes = 2**16-1  # 65535
out = chan.recv(nbytes)
while out != b'':  # or: out != ''
    if b'\n' in out or b'\r' in out:
        parts = out.splitlines()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, the method always returns `bytes`.

In Python 2, the method returns a string.

Comment: Alternately: it simply returns `bytes`  (since in 2.x, `bytes` and `str` are the same thing).